# Object in django admin for a foreignkey :

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have this object in my django model :

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
    def ___str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I see it in the django admin it works well.

But in the admin when I want to see this object :

```
class StockData(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock,on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True,blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    interval = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=2)

    def ___str__(self):
        return self.stock+ ":" + str(self.date)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stock + ":" + str(self.date)
```

with this admin :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import StockData

# Register your models here.
class StockData_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'date',
        'stock',
        'interval'
    )

admin.site.register(StockData,StockData_Admin)
```

but in the admin page the stock object is represented as :

```
Stock object (1)
```

edit :

[image]

So how to solve this ?

My django version :

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION 
(2, 0, 0, 'final', 0)
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: Drop interval from list_display in StockData_Admin class

Comment: @MohammadAli doesn't work :/

Comment: in stock table  name maybe return null value (empty string)  and in Stock data model also stock maybe null(empty). So in that case what to you want to display ?. It is not clear what do you want to display. See the example of birth date https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis edited

Comment: In your models (null=True, blank=True)  allow null values (empty strings) so do you want to have empty strings ?. Especially it is not best practice to have null values in foreign keys

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis even with null=false i have stock  Objects

Comment: another way you can fix this - you can add special method to your `StockData_Admin` which will return the related `Stock` name - and show this name as a field in admin.

Comment: also you have a typo  magic methods are with 2 underscores   in stock model you have 3  in str method

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis even correcting the typo does not solve my problem :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a typo in your `Stock` definition - Python's magic methods start and end with double underscore, `Stock`'s **str** currently starts with three underscores instead of two. When the `Stock` instance is printed, it falls back to the `models.Model` [default str implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L504). Once the suprefluous underscore is removed, you will see the `Stock` displayed correctly:

[image: Fixed admin dashboad]

Answer (score 0):

In models.py  try something like this (not tested)

```
class Stock(models.Model):

  name =  models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=20)
  # charfield default value is empty string so null true not needed

  def __str__(self):
    title = 'Empty title'
    if self.name != '':
        title = self.name
    return title

  def __unicode__(self):
    title = 'Empty title'
    if self.name != '':
        title = self.name
    return title

class StockData(models.Model):
   stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock,on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True,blank=True)
   date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
   interval = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=2)

   def __str__(self):
      title = 'Empty title'
      if(all([self.stock, self.date])):
         title = '{}:{}'.format(self.stock, self.date)
      return title

   def __unicode__(self):
     title = ''
     if self.stock and self.date:
        title = self.stock + ':' + self.date
     return title
```

in admin.py try this

```
class StockData_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display = (
    'get_date',
    'get_stock',
    'get_interval'
 )

 def get_date(self, obj):
     return obj.date

 def get_stock(self, obj):
     return obj.stock

 def get_interval(self, obj):
     return obj.interval

 get_date.empty_value_display = 'No available date'
 get_stock.empty_value_display = 'No available stock'
 get_interval.empty_value_display = 'No available interval'

 admin.site.register(StockData,StockData_Admin)
```